# Visual Studio Online can't locate function in class in class library on build server

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, tfs

Hi I'm getting an error in the VSO log and a build failure

> d:\a\src-***--\r2rJSONcall.aspx.vb (31): 'rptJSONRoutesTable' is not
>   a member of 'r2rSearchResponse'.

And yet it is!

r2rJSONcall.aspx.vb

```
Public Class r2rJSONcall
 ...

  Property r2rResponse As New r2rSearchResponse
   ...

   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


  'call the webservice..
  ...

   Response.Write(r2rResponse.rptJSONRoutesTable("EUR"))
```

and in a classlibrary..

```
Public Class r2rSearchResponse
  ...
  Function rptJSONRoutesTable(userCurrencyCode) As String
```

It, of course, runs locally no problem.

I've tried making a one byte change and recommitting, also the associated DLL was under source control, so I removed and add that.   No Joy.

UPDATE -  no, bad news the answer I posted below solved the problem temporarily. It has reared its ugly head once more and no matter what can't seem to get a build to work.

The following procedures have been tried so far to get a VSO online build to compile correctly:

1)  I deleted my local folders and performed a full checkout from sourcecontrol - suggested by @MetaFight.  That compiles fine locally, no files missing.

2) Excluded the /Bin and /Obj folders.  So no dll's checked into source as suggested by @PhilipKendall

3) Run MSBuild locally.  The solution compiles OK.

4) Renamed, and then moved function inside the classlib to try to trigger rebuild on Azure server.   Still can't find the function.

5) Checked build order, Classlib is compiled first.  "Clean" option selected on Build Profile.

6) Checked that references are correct.  I can see the reference in the vbproj file.  The reference are Project references, not file references.

7) Deleted Build Profile in Azure/VSO.  Created new build defintition profile and new Web App in Azure - error reappears.

8) Tried this solution [Library/Static Method not Updating in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897664/library-static-method-not-updating-in-azure)   No Merge error like point 3) on that page.

Any TFS/VSO experts out there can help?

Comment: Try building from a fresh checkout.  That might highlight any files you may have forgotten to add to source control.

Comment: Pull out dotPeek or whatever your favourite .NET decompiler is and check that the function *really* is in the DLL.

Comment: @MetaFight - sorry I'm a complete noob here.  What you mean "building from a fresh checkout"

Comment: @PhilipKendall I got a copy of Telerik's decompiler - what fun!  The build server is in Azure cloud, so I FTP'ed in and downloaded the ClassLib.dll and compared it to my local - yes there is no function in the remote version - so what do I next.  I copied the website.dll and the classlib.dlls down and then deleted the remote ones - hoping it would rebuild them - but rechecking in just fails and the site doesn't work - any ideas, remember I'm clueless.  Help gratefully received.

Comment: OK, so you need to understand your build process and how that DLL gets built. We can't help with that because you're obviously doing something other than just a straight build from source, because you're checking DLLs into source control.

Comment: Yes the DLLs into source are a problem, because there is always a conflict on checkin.  I am using Azure with CI.  When someone does a commit the source is built by VSO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for not coming back sooner.

As discussed the problem came back even though it did manage to build after checkin from the rogue programmer, it subsequently went back to not building.

In the end we renamed the classlib (by right clicking and rename).   Then checked the references to that classlib from all the other projects that require it.   There was one subproject that on "add.. reference..." did not have the checkbox on, but in Properties of the project and references did.  So this must have re-established the line in the vbproj file correctly.

Congo we build!

Answer (score 1):

We working in a small team and new member with no VSO experience has come onboard.  He's working on the frontside AJAX, JSON, CSS, HTML5 - no need to use the classlibs or anything else - just submitting his code via TFS.

I suspected he might be an issue, so fixed up remote access and went in.   He'd not updated Windows 7 since new - around 4 years.  "Never had a BSOD" was the response.  He was trying to install IIS which the machine wasn't very happy about it, so could not test locally, I don't know what the webserver in Visual Studio was doing - his system was not in English.  Anyway I right-clicked where I would have done on the English version and did a recursive pull - then clicked on what looked like the Pending Changes and did a checkin.

Success - solution built OK.

I told my programmer to delete Visual Studio and never do a checkout again on that PC - and am providing him a remote desktop with fully patched machine and software.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following methods:

1) Did you check "Enable Nuget Package Restore" for your project?

You can use the following documentation for doing that:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Or:

2) Read the source below, it may help you if first method is not applicable for you or don't help:

http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2013/08/31/are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference-why-yes-i-am-so-kind-of-you-to-ask/

I hope both offered method support your question.

Comment: These are good 3rd party library solutions.  Our problem was more fundamental - it was a reference to a class written and compiled by us, and wholly contained within our solution